# How to store the json response in memory in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, memory

Hey I am calling one route from my nodejs application. It returns the JSON. I want to to store that json into memory.

What is the way to do this in nodejs ?

Comment: into memory? like, in a **var**iable?

Comment: That's almost the definition of too-broad a question. Try to be more specific about what you actually mean. Just about every API has the default action of storing the response in memory anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your JSON response on the `global` object (which happens to be in memory)

```
function handleResponse(err, result){
    if(err){
        //handle error
    }
    global.jsonData = result;
}
```

EDIT: All variables are in memory. I'm assuming here that you want to store it in one function and access it somewhere else at a later point in time

Comment: what is global here ?

Comment: `global` is the root global object in NodeJS (similar to `window` on browsers). You can access it's properties from anywhere using `global.propertyName`. Care must be taken if the variables are initialized asynchronously

Comment: when I stop nodejs application then value retains there still ?

Comment: No.. Since it is in memory, you will lose it. You can optionally write the response to a JSON file on disk and read it from there. But I can't think of a reason why you would do that as you can always hit your API when the application starts and load it back into memory. If you need it only once, you can always just hit the API, copy the values into a JSON file and read that file every time your application starts